# Collaborative Maximum Costly Sequential Multi-armed Bandit

Tags: multiarmed-bandit

My problem is similar to the multi-armed bandit problem in that I need to allocate "pulls" between `n` options, each giving a stochastic real reward. The pulls for a given arm are IID.

Differences:

1. I want to maximize the maximum reward. I do not care about the sum of rewards.
2. Each arm has a list of the results of all of previous pulls attached to it.
3. I access the arms sequentially. I can only access an arm's previous pulls while accessing that arm. After each new pull, I must decide whether to pull again or to continue to the next arm. A pull costs 1. The cost of going to the next arm is `C`, a strictly positive real number. (`C` is probably greater than 1, but I'll need to measure that).
4. Each time I reach my last arm, I can start again, but for each pull I made, there will be one new arm with one pull recorded.
5. I have a notebook in which I can write down a little information to carry from arm to arm.
6. I am part of a small team. After each pass through the arms, we can confer and update our notebooks. Then we divide up the arms evenly among ourselves and start again.
7. There is a limited budget. When we have spent everything, we stop.

Has this (or a similar) problem been studied? Similar problems could be quite helpful: for example, problems that ignore the sequential nature, the increasing number of arms, the costs, and/or the team. However, keeping only the maximum reward rather than all rewards is essential.

[I made another question out of one useful simplification](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/187095/6665).

**edit** Clarified costs because of a comment by [armen-aghajanyan](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/98200/armen-aghajanyan)

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by: "The cost of going to the next arm is C times the cost of a pull". Is the cost of the pull a separate constant?

Comment: @ArmenAghajanyan I modified the description to clarify costs. The pull is a different constant, but since those are the only two budgetary factors, I can just divide the budget by the cost of a pull. So, in the description, I just set the cost of a pull to 1.

Comment: So is the goal to maximize the reward while minimizing the total cost?

Comment: @ArmenAghajanyan The goal is to maximize the reward on a fixed budget. I find problems of the form "maximize x while minimizing y" to be ill-defined - you always have to specify some fudge factor for the tradeoff. I'd also be interested in maximizing the reward in a fixed number of passes through all the arms.

Comment: Thank you. I am currently working on a solution in my free time. I'll get back to you as soon as possible.